# Searching files in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to make a command that searches, in parallel, a given number of files for a given word, where...

```
ppatternsearch [-p n] word {files}
```

1. `ppatternsearch` is the command name
2. `-p` is an option that defines the level of parallelization
3. `n` is the number of processes/threads that the -p option will
   create for the word search
4. `word` is the word I'll be searching for
5. `files` is, as you can imagine, the files I'll be searching through.

I want to do this in 2 ways - one with `processes` and another with `threads`. In the end, the parent process/main thread returns the number of lines where it found the word that was being searched.

Thing is, I've developed some code already and I've hit a wall. I have no idea where to go from here.

```
import argparse, os, sys, time

num_lines_with_pattern = []

def pattern_finder(pattern, file_searched):
    counter = 0
    with open(file_searched, 'r') as ficheiro_being_read:
        for line in ficheiro_being_read:
            if pattern in line:
                print line
                counter += 1
    num_lines_with_pattern.append(counter)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-p', type = int, default = 1, help = Defines command parallelization.')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

The next step is it import `threading` or `multiprocessing` and launch `pattern_finder` the appropriate number of times.

You'll probably also want to look into `queue.Queue` so your results aren't printed jumbled up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be I/O bound and therefore introducing multiple threads/processes won't make your hard disk work any faster.

Though it should be easy to check. To run `pattern_finder()` using a process pool:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def pattern_finder(pattern, file_searched):
    ...
    return file_searched, number_of_lines_with_pattern

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(n or cpu_count() + 1) 
    search = partial(pattern_finder, word)
    for filename, count in pool.imap_unordered(search, files):
        print("Found {count} lines in {filename}".format(**vars()))
```